# My keyboard completely freezes after halt/suspend (Loki 0.4.1). How do I fix this?

Tags: greeter, keyboard

My laptop is basically unusable after waking up because the keyboard freezes. The only difference between waking up after suspend and waking up after halt is that after halting, even the lock screen doesn't show up (only the elementary os logo stays on screen for like forever).

How can I go about fixing this?

Side note: what is a good resource for understanding how the OS is put together? If I encounter a problem I want to be able to figure out the location of the relevant files and how they work so that I can fix or change things on my own.

Answer (score 0):

it's possibly a power management issue.

does removing the keyboard and plugging it back in resolve the issue?

As for resources I find the Arch wiki pages to be well written, some of the information needs to be changed because ubuntu uses a different folder stucture, but most of the info still applies.  https://wiki.archlinux.org/

There's also the Ubuntu manual pages. http://manpages.ubuntu.com/